# How can I request location permission when clicking on the MyLocation button?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions, android-maps

I want to request location permission when the user clicks on the `MyLocation` button.

I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location) but they have requested location permission when the activity starts. But I want to request permission when clicking on the `MyLocation` button.

I searched on the whole internet to find anyone who has faced the same problem but I did not find anything.

This command `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` does not work without grant location permission.

`MyLocation` button is an optional feature and not required inside my app.

Is it possible to do something like that or I should find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **enableMyLocation()** function call from **onMapReady()** callback, and call it in **onMyLocationButtonClick()**. Like mentioned below:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
}
```

And then

```
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    enableMyLocation();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
    // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I cannot show the `MyLocation` button without granting location permission, So if I try to show the button without granting location permission I'll get this error `java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: What is the difference between `setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener` and `setOnMyLocationClickListener`?

Comment: In that case use this command with `false`. eg: `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` this will work and won't ask for permission. Other code you can use as you have used.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I want to show the `MyLocation` button regardless of whether the location permission was granted or not.